# standard representation of $su(2)$ on $\Bbb{C}^2$ is irreducible

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $\text{su}(2)$ be the Lie algebra associated to the Lie group $\text{SU}(2)$, consider the representation of $\text{su}(2)$ on $\Bbb{C}^2$ as :

$$\rho:\text{su}(2) \to \text{GL}(2,\Bbb{C})\\ A \mapsto A$$

Prove this representation is irreducible.

My attempt: assume the proper subspace $W \subset \Bbb{C}^2$ invariant under $A \in \text{su}(2) = \{M\in M_2(\Bbb{C})\mid \text{tr}(M) = 0 \text{ and } M+M^H = 0\}$.

Since all the nonzero proper subspace of $\Bbb{C}^2$ has the form $\Bbb{C}v$ for some $v\in \Bbb{C}^2$ being invariant under $A$ means it's eigenvector of $A\in \text{su}(2)$,  in particular ,it must lies in the eigenspace for three of the Pauli matrices, but it can be checked there is no $v\in \Bbb{C}^2$ can be eigenvector for all Pauli matrices.

Is my interpretation correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Depending on your background, you might want to be more explicit about the "it can be checked ..." part at the end.

Comment: It can be checked easily since the common eigenvalue are $\lambda = +1/-1$, therefore $\sigma_i v = v$ or $\sigma_i v = -v$ in both case $v$ has to be zero. @Torsten Schoeneberg